# Customize accessdenied.aspx in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a web in Sharepoint 2007. I have sites with permission for certain roles. When a user with a role that has not got permission to enter the site, Sharepoint redirects him/her to accessdenied.aspx which has Sharepoint design.
How can I change this redirection so that it goes to a customized one? I don't know if the server will be shared with other Sharepoint webs, so i don't dare to edit accesdenied.aspx directly (i have not verified if i can anyway).

I would need precise code and indications, because i am no guru of Sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I could offer you more in terms of precise code, but [this website](http://balajinjl.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/customizing-access-denied-page-in-moss-2007/) seems to have pretty clear instructions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think i would choose one of the links mentioned in this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/bgeoffro/archive/2007/11/12/branding-a-moss-corporate-intranet-portal-part-3-layouts-pages.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check this article for the issue you face when you create your own custom access denied error page and solution proposed in my post.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9332cbe8-fda4-48de-a397-5f42bff9bf73/sharepoint-2010-custom-access-denied-page

Thanks & Regards,

Syed Abbas

Comment: For the 2013 version - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31253.sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-custom-access-denied-page.aspx   - noting that a link is good, but copying the steps into an answer here is better as external pages may not always be available.

Comment: Yeah you are right as myself have faced this issue :)
thanks for pointing it out,